# Adding a Compiler PreprocessorDefinitions in VS2010 C++ based on the value of %(Link->SubSystem)

Tags: msbuild

I would have expected the following snippet of msbuild to work at the bottom of my .vcxproj files:

```
 <ItemDefinitionGroup>
   <ClCompile>
<PreprocessorDefinitions Condition='%(Link.SubSystem)'=='Windows'>SomethingWinSpecific;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
   </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

except no matter what I do `%(Link.SubSystem)` is empty.  I even printed out its value in various targets throughout a build and it appears to remain empty until the Link step begins.  So my question is, is there any way to access the value of Link.SubSystem before the Compile step?

Comment: Does the `Platform` variable not give you the distinction you need?

Answer (score 0):

Link.SubSystem distinquishes between a Windows app and Console App, so Platform will not work.